# Expression for transitive matrices

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to find a mathematical expression for the number of all possible transitive boolean matrices of order nxn.
For example,

$$T_1^n = n(n - 1)^3 + \frac{1}{6}n(n - 1)^4(n - 2) + \frac{1}{6}n(n - 1)(n - 2)(4n - 1)$$

This expresion T_1 works for only those transitive boolean matrices which has 3 nonzero elements. For example in 3x3 there are 43 transitive matrices, for 4x4 there are 276 having only 3 nonzero elements.

$$T_2^n = \frac{1}{2}n(n - 1)(n^2 - n + 3)$$

T_2 works for the number of n × n transitive Boolean matrices with two nonzero elements.

Now I am looking for an expression which can give the number of transitive Boolean matrices in nxn transitive boolean matrices with 4 non-zero elements in each transitive Boolean matrix.

Here is what I know about the total numbers of transitive Boolean matriceswith 4 non-zero elements in each transitive Boolean matrix.

[image: TBMwith4-nonzero]

Is it possible to generalize this information?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).